# PageMethod and Partial PostBack and determine response size

Tags: asp.net, pagemethods

is there any way out to detect the full postback is occurred or partial postback occur when we work with PageMethod. if firebug is install then how could i check the size of response. can anyone help me to detect it because in my case pagemethod is taking bit more time to send back the response to client. i am not very aware the use of firebug. how to check the response size with fire but when partial postback will occur with the help of pagemethod. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have partial postbacks then you are probably either [using page methods as web-services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163480.aspx#S5) or something (like the [UpdatePannel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx)) that requires a [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx).

If you are using **page methods**, you can check the page's [IsCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.iscallback.aspx) property which returns true if the page request is the result of a callback; otherwise, false.

If you have a **ScriptManager** on the page you can use its [IsInAsyncPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.iscallback.aspx) which returns true if the current postback is executing in partial-rendering mode; otherwise, false.